# What is the XNA 4.0 equivalent of GraphicsDevice.CheckDepthStencilMatch?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I've been trying to work through a tutorial which I foresee will be very helpful to my current project, but it was target at XNA 3.1.  Thus, many sections of code (which the author does not explain too much) are now obsolete.  Here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dwCx9Xsb) of the file.  The main thing that sticks out to me is the GraphicsDevice.CheckDepthStencilMatch function.  I can't seem to find out much about it.  Is it even necessary anymore?  As you can see I've commented out some of the sections which I think are no longer required.

Comment: Can you link your tutorial that you are following?

Comment: http://xnameetingpoint.web.officelive.com/EnglishPlanets1.aspx  I have also asked the author to update, but he has not gotten back to me.  I've actually already sort of gotten past what this question was about (I eliminated anything to do with DepthStencils entirely), but now I'm having problems with the shader.  Something about VS3.0 and PS3.0 requiring stuff that's not included there.

Comment: I'll take a look over the weekend and see if I can convert it.

Comment: Wow, you have no idea how helpful this would be to me.  Take your time!  I will continue to see if I can work it out myself, but I'm afraid most of this is above me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out XNA 4.0 method: [GraphicsAdapter.QueryRenderTargetFormat Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsadapter.queryrendertargetformat.aspx)

The description for it:

> Queries the adapter for support for the requested render target
>   format.

I believe this is what you're looking for.

Let me know if you need specific code sample or anything else.